# Visual Studio references search returns duplicate results

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have a .NET Standard project that when I "Find all references" on an item, I am getting 3 results for every match found.  See the image below (vertically cropped for readability).  Is there a way to prevent this from occuring?

[image]